# Combine gridview rows and eliminate duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have 2 tables:

```
Table 1

id   question   customerId
1     bla1         1
2     bla2         2    

Table 2

id    customerId    Key         Value
1      1           firstname    John
2      1           lastname     Doe
3      2           firstname    Billy
4      2           lastname     Jones
```

I need to get my gridview to show:

```
Row 1: John Doe        Bla1
Row 2: Billy Jones     Bla2
```

Currently it shows: (but I dont want it like this):

```
Row 1: John      Bla1
Row 2: Doe       Bla1
Row 3: Billy     Bla2
Row 4: Jones     Bla2
```

I think I have tried everything and could use your help! Thanks.

Comment: If you want to solve it in SQL, you want table expressions maybe: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  [firstname],[lastname], question
FROM
        (
            SELECT  a.question, b.[key], b.[value]
            FROM    Table1 a
                    INNER JOIN Table2 b
                        ON a.customerID = b.CustomerID
        ) org
        PIVOT
        (
            MAX([value])
            FOR [KEY] IN ([firstname],[lastname])
        ) pvt
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71db7/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ FIRSTNAME ║ LASTNAME ║ QUESTION ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ John      ║ Doe      ║ bla1     ║
║ Billy     ║ Jones    ║ bla2     ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: +1 for SQL Fiddle. Thats very interesting :) I had to create the structure on my DB to test.

Comment: I am using gridview and I get error for DataKeyNames="Id" "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'." What do I put for DataKeyNames?

Comment: Nevermind, I just take out DataKeyNames altogether. Thank you for the sweet solution. you must be a genius!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [firstname],[lastname], question
FROM
(
    SELECT Q.ID, Question, Q.CUSTOMERID, KeyId, KeyValue 
    FROM QUESTION Q
            INNER JOIN CUSTOMERMAP C ON Q.CUSTOMERID=C.CUSTOMERID
) as Data
PIVOT
(
   MAX(KeyValue)
   FOR KeyId in ([firstname],[lastname])
) as PT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the data for binding grid using below query:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.Question,
    (SELECT Value + ' ' FROM Table2 b WHERE b.customerId=a.customerid 
        FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)') Value
FROM Table1 a
```